# Save current state of the application and load it back into the application in WXpython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have developed an application in wxpython and now I want to save the state of the application so that I can load the application in the same state when I reopen it.
I think I need to code for this. Can any one help me trying this? I have flatnote book, splitter windows and many such widgets in the application. I tried saving the objects using pickle but got an error saying "Pyswig objects cannot be stored".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PersistenceManager can take care of most of that. See http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/Phoenix/lib.agw.persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager.html for more information.

Comment: But i don't find a way to install the latest wxpython that has persistent module in it.

Comment: It should be in the wx.lib.agw part. I see it in my wxPython 2.9 demo under PersistentControls, but I know you can get it for 2.8 although you might have to get it from SVN.